# Rendered textures, spots instead of smooth

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

[Rendered Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JqWm.jpg)

Hello,

when I render my scene, the walls windows and ceiling have weird
spots on them.

What should I do?

Thanks, Daniel

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Read this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/scene/render_layers/denoising.html)

What you have here is denoising artefacts from the blender denoiser. The solution to them is increasing your render samples or not using the denoiser at all.